# MagicLine jQuery - length of underline

Tags: jquery, css, navigation, underline

I tried to use MagicLine jQuery Navigation on my website, but I've run into a small problem. 
I want the underline to be precisely as long as the word that it's currently highlighting. Instead it's a few pixels longer and I simply can't deal with that. I tried to fix it with CSS but I failed. I believe the solution of this problem can be found in jQuery code, but I'm not familiar with it so I'm asking you for help. **How to shorten the length of the underline in jQuery?**

[Here](http://css-tricks.com/jquery-magicline-navigation/) you can find MagicLine jQuery Navigation and [here](http://i50.tinypic.com/1zoz1hd.png) a graphic description of my problem.

Comment: Can you create a http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: @ArunPJohny Unfortunately, I don't know why, but MagicLine doesn't work in jsfiddle. But you can find the preview of my website here [link]http://przewoski.com/v2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I make some tweaks to make it fit for your requirement

```
$("#example-one li").find("a").hover(function() {
    $el = $(this);
    var padding = ($el.outerWidth() - $el.width()) / 2;
    console.log($el.outerWidth(),$el.width(), padding)
    leftPos = $el.position().left + padding;
    newWidth = $el.width();

    $magicLine.stop().animate({
        left: leftPos,
        width: newWidth
    });
}, function() {
    $magicLine.stop().animate({
        left: $magicLine.data("origLeft"),
        width: $magicLine.data("origWidth")
    });    
});
```

Also need to change the `current_page_item` also

```
var $currentItem =  $(".current_page_item a");
var padding = ($currentItem.outerWidth() - $currentItem.width()) / 2;

$magicLine
    .width($currentItem.width())
    .css("left", $currentItem.position().left + padding)
    .data("origLeft", $magicLine.position().left )
    .data("origWidth", $magicLine.width());
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UbAz4/1/)

Comment: Thank you, that's almost what I wanted! Although there is still one more thing. Underline under ".current_page_item" li ("HOME" in this case) still extends outside the word. You can see the difference when it's hovered and when it's left. Can you do something about it?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution `.navigation ul li.active { 
                          margin-right: -10px; 
                        }`

You need to give this CSS to it.

Comment: Unfortunately it's not a solution. Here you can see **before** [before]http://przewoski.com/v2 and **after** [after]http://przewoski.com/v2/v2.1

Comment: I can just check and let you know again.